# jQuery - Get index of clicked item from list of elements with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a collection of elements in this format:

```
<div class="row feed">

    <div class="col-sm-4 inner"><span></span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inner"><span></span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inner"><span></span></div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 inner"><span></span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inner"><span></span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inner"><span></span></div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

</div>
```

I am trying to get the index of the parent when a `span` is clicked. This works fine but if I click the 4th, 5th or 6th then the number is incorrect as it counts the clearfix div as an index.

I can't simply add 1 to the result as this format is dynamic and it grows, hence the maths could get complicated fast.

Instead is there a way to specify to only get the index of certain objects, I thought the following may do what I wanted but it doesn't seem to?

```
$(document).on("click", ".feed .inner span", function(){

    var activeElement = $(this).parent();

    console.log($(".feed:not(.clearfix)").index(activeElement));
});
```

but that just gives `-1` which means no element found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function you can pass an argument to tell it to get the index relative to a group of elements.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".feed .inner span", function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().index('div.col-sm-6.inner'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row feed">
    <div class="col-sm-6 inner"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 inner"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 inner"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 inner"><span>4</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 inner"><span>5</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 inner"><span>6</span></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
</div>
```

Per the docs for `.index()`:

> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, `.index()` returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
>   element is not found, `.index()` will return -1.

Answer (score 1):

try change it to

```
console.log(activeElement.index(".inner"));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the parent element of the clicked element doesn't exist in the `$(".feed:not(.clearfix)")` collection. You should select the children of the `.feed` element instead of the `.feed` element. One option is:

```
$(".feed > div:not(.clearfix)").index(activeElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You need to get the index relative to the direct children of the `.feed` element.

The parent element of `this` isn't in the root of the collection `.feed:not(.clearfix)`, therefore you need to select the direct children of `.feed` instead. In doing so, the index will be relative to the direct children elements of `.feed` rather than `.feed` itself.

In the example below, the direct [child selector, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors), is used:

```
$(document).on("click", ".feed .inner span", function() {
    var index = $(".feed > :not(.clearfix)").index($(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you only try to add a property to your html

then you only need something like this $( "[data-index='1']" )